# iOS notifications

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

I'd like my app to have save a username and password for each user and login with it, unless it is changed to another user.
I was asking myself how I can send the Push notifications to the relevant device ?

What kind of data do I need to send alongside the username and password each time a username/password have changed or newly entered ?

Comment: Have you considered using a platform like Parse?  We create a new channel with the users id in it.  When we want to send a push to that user we simply send a push to the channel for their id.  It's a very simple platform with their SDK.

Answer (score 4):

Implement this method in your AppDelegate, the value of "str" represents the unique string for the device.  Use this in addition to username and password to uniquely identify a user on a specific device.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken { 

    NSString *str = [NSString 
        stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];
    NSLog(str);

}
```

A prerequisite for this is to call this line of code somewhere in your application, usually from applicationDidFinishLaunching

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
    registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
    (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | 
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | 
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

This is a very good end to end reference on programming iOS Push Notifications (scroll way down past the configuration information to find the programming techniques): http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services